# Cannot find libraries added from github in native PHP

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I'm working on a native PHP project. Using terminal in the root I added 2 github libraries and they get saved in the vendor folder. In a sub folder in the root in a PHP file I add

```
use nadar\quill\Lexer;
$lexer = new Lexer($row['reply']);
echo $lexer->render();
```

But I get

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'nadar\quill\Lexer' not found in /home/USER/public_html/production/filename.php:469
```

I tried another library and get the same error Cannot find the class. How to solve this? Tis is the first library url: https://github.com/nadar/quill-delta-parser

Comment: create an alias for the namespace (e.g. lexer): `use nadar\quill\Lexer as lexer;` which you can use to instantiate your class: `$lexer = new lexer\Lexer($row['reply']);`

Comment: So, you manually added the libraries to the vendor folder? This won't just work, you need a package manager like [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to generate an autoload file that will load these classes for you.

Comment: @Jerodev Added using composer not manually

Comment: ^-- this, or use [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: @jibsteroos  Class 'nadar\quill\Lexer\Lexer' not found

Comment: Hi @PHPUser, i have added the `require` section to the readme file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every file where you need classes loaded by the autoloader need to include the autoload file. Otherwise, these classes are unknown by the interpreter.

Add this to the beginning of your file:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```